# Attach pdf to e-mail. Message doesn't work

Tags: php, pdf, sendmail

This php script works just fine sending my pdf file by e-mail.

The problem is the script doesn't send any message as specified in $mainMessage.

Why do that problem occur, with the script only sending the pdf file without any message?

```
// Settings
    $name        = "Name";
    $email       = "someome@anadress.com";
    $to          = "$name <$email>";
    $from        = "email@email.com";
    $subject     = "Here is your attachment";
    $mainMessage = "Hi, here's the file.";
    $fileatt     = "test.pdf";
    $fileatttype = "application/pdf";
    $fileattname = "newname.pdf";
    $headers = "From: $from";

    // File
    $file = fopen($fileatt, 'rb');
    $data = fread($file, filesize($fileatt));
    fclose($file);

    // This attaches the file
    $semi_rand     = md5(time());
    $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";
    $headers      .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
    "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" .
    " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";
    $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
    "-{$mime_boundary}\n" .
    "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\n" .
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
    $mainMessage  . "\n\n";
    $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
    $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
    "Content-Type: {$fileatttype};\n" .
    " name=\"{$fileattname}\"\n" .
    "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" .
    " filename=\"{$fileattname}\"\n" .
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
    $data . "\n\n" .
    "-{$mime_boundary}-\n";

    // Send the email
    if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
        echo "The email was sent.";
    }
    else {
        echo "There was an error sending the mail.";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `\r\n` instead of your `\n`s. Also, I would suggest using a library for sending emails, such as [PHPMailer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/) or [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/), instead.

**EDIT:** There appears to be an extra (or missing) `"` when you declare your charset (at `"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\n"` - it outputs `Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1`).

Comment: That unfortunately doesn't work. Do you have any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you didn't notice that you need to complete this line:

```
 $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n" .
               "--{$mime_boundary}\r\n" .
               "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8 \r\n" .
               "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n" .
                $mainMessage  . "\r\n\r\n";
```

you are missing one "-" in "-{$mime_boundary}\r\n".
it should be as the example I wrote :3